# Wiki for the 50+ Crowd?

Tags: wiki, elderly

This sounds like a crazy question but...can anybody recommend wiki software that the 50+ crowd could follow?

I'd prefer if it:

- Ran on Linux
- Include Categories and Tags
- Is smart phone and printer friendly

Comment: Can you clarify the ways in which you feel the "50+ crowd" have special needs?   How should answers differ for your question than for an equivalent question without the "that the 50+ crowd could follow" clause?

Comment: @CPerkins As soon as ya post a question like this the 50+ crowd that uses wikis come outta the woodwork!  But in my town it's hard to find even a 20-something that even knows what a wiki is!!!

Comment: For one they don't know much about syntax; maybe I should have made it 75+

Comment: Can I limit the question to just people in my community and get on with it; I'm trying to help them in their community building efforts.

Comment: So you're looking for a wiki with extremely simple syntax?   Any other requirements?

Comment: Tags and Categories...but I guess that makes it less than simple eh?

Comment: Is Markdown simple enough?  They don't have to *use* all of the available complexity.  Or (and I haven't used this, but the description looks like it might be a good match for you): DokuWiki   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DokuWiki

Comment: That's true, as the moderator I could probably help them with advanced stuff.   But as the bare minimum I'd like to teach them how to link

Comment: FYI, meta post about the tags here: [Should we have the elderly and non-tech-savy tags?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2455/46)